# Is there a way to force the focus on a determined window tab?

Tags: javascript, events, servicenow

A little bit of background: I'm working with ServiceNow and we're trying to build a custom UI Page/Portal Widget that can listen to an external barcode scanner, this solution is mobile-focused. The plan is to use a Mobile Web Screen so we can call this page from the ServiceNow Agent App. (OOTB Barcode Scanner via mobile does not meet our business needs).

The challenge I'm facing right now is that I have a simple HTML page with an input, and then I added a load event to focus the input after the page loads.

This works well if we try the page from desktop, but once we try it from the mobile app, it doesn't work.

[Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxnGD.png) vs
[Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxQ8i.png)

I have tried a bunch of different things:

- `$j( '#input_asset_tag' ).focus();`
- `window.focus()`
- `document.activeelement.blur()`
- `$j( '#input_asset_tag' ).click();`

I realized that the mobile window does not have a focus when it is opened by adding this line of code to the load event:
`alert( 'Has focus: '+ document.hasFocus() );`

So now when the page is opened I get an alert that tells me if the document has focus.
In desktop returns true, but mobile returns false:
[Desktop has focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6SiS.png) vs [Mobile has no focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McIZD.png)

The main issue is that the mobile web window is not focused by default. I tried setting a timeout and after 5 seconds ran this line: `$j( '#input_asset_tag' ).focus();`, Then opened the mobile web screen, tab on any part of the screen before the 5 seconds were reached and then that worked, the input got focused.

Also, I tried adding another event "keypress" so we can listen to the external barcode scanner this way, but it doesn't seem to work until you set the focus on the window (tab on any part of the screen).

We need this solution to work without the user having to click on the screen, the only responsibility of the user should be to press the scan button on the hardware to scan barcodes and leave the rest to the app.

*$j('element') is the syntax used in ServiceNow to call jQuery.

*This is how the load event looks like:

```
window.addEventListener( 'load', function(){
    $j( '#input_asset_tag' ).focus();
    alert( 'Has focus: '+ document.hasFocus() );

});
```

I found an article stating this depends entirely on the browser and we don't have too much control over this, but I'm still not convinced.

Comment: Have you tried simply using the `autofocus` input attribute? Like so: `<input name="yourInput" type="text" id="yourInput" value="" autofocus>`

Comment: "but I'm still not convinced" ... did you try it in different browsers?

Comment: Seems you should be calling focus() when jquery's document ready or simply use vanilla javascript in your event listener

Comment: How are you loading your scripts? Order makes a difference, and if you're using `type=module`, then the 'load' event may never fire. You could also try removing the event listener and see if your code throws any errors.

Comment: @FiddlingAway I tried the autoFocus attribute as well, and it does not work in mobile.

Comment: @GetSet I tried in google chrome mobile and although the screen keyboard does not show up the input is focused, but when I tried using the embedded web screen in the ServiceNow app it did not work.
I also tried both vanilla javascript and jQuery .ready function, same behavior.

Comment: @Josh the load event is being fired, for example, if I do other things like simulate a button click or display an alert, those things work. I also tried having a button that when on click set the focus on the input, and simulated a click on that button when the document loads but didn't work on mobile.

Comment: Why do you need to "focus the input after the page loads"? This may be an XY problem and is why I am asking. .... Is it that the barcode is supposed to go into this field, and if so, why not just open the page with the barcode embedded in the url? That is provided you have the control to open the page in the 1st place, timed to the barcode hardware trigger.

Comment: @RamónCordova - If you're sure that the event is firing, then the next steps would be to ensure that the selector/id is not returning `null`. If the element is being loaded asynchronously, then it's possible that it will sometimes appear to work and other times it won't.